# OpenCV to align images fails when ignoring orientation on gray scale conversion

Tags: python, opencv

I am using Python and OpenCV to align images [using the code found here](https://learnopencv.com/image-alignment-ecc-in-opencv-c-python/).  This works fine except that OpenCV is honoring the EXIF image rotation values in the final output.  While the two images are aligned perfectly in the OpenCV viewer the saved image is rotated 180 degrees to the second image.   I am using QGIS to process the data and the OpenCV aligned image is rotated 180 degrees from the image it was aligned to.

Found that I can alter to code  to ignore the image rotation when first opening the images as shown below.

```
 im1 = cv2.imread(path_to_image_1, cv2.IMREAD_IGNORE_ORIENTATION)

 im1_gray = cv2.cvtColor(im1, cv2COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

This works fine but when I get the the next section of the code that converts the image to gray scale I get error message.

```
  File "/home/gerry/Python/GeotaggedImageFootprintsToShp/OpenCV_Image_Alignment.py", line 17, in <module>
  im1_gray = cv2.cvtColor(im1,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.1) /tmp/pip-req-build-ms668fyv/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.simd_helpers.hpp:92: error: (-2:Unspecified error) in function 'cv::impl:    
{anonymous}::CvtHelper<VScn, VDcn, VDepth, sizePolicy>::CvtHelper(cv::InputArray, cv::OutputArray, int) [with VScn = cv::impl::{anonymous}::Set<3, 4>; VDcn = cv::impl::
{anonymous}::Set<1>; VDepth = cv::impl::{anonymous}::Set<0, 2, 5>; cv::impl::{anonymous}::SizePolicy sizePolicy = cv::impl::<unnamed>::NONE; cv::InputArray = const cv::_InputArray&; cv::OutputArray = const cv::_OutputArray&]'
> Invalid number of channels in input image:
> 'VScn::contains(scn)'
> where
> 'scn' is 1
```

How can I ignore image rotation in the final saved image and still convert the open image to gray scale?

Comment: Why not correct the orientation before processing. The EXIF orientation has a flag that tells you how it was rotated. So you can read that and then correct the rotation to its proper orientation. Then do your processing.

Comment: You mean open the image in OpenCV with rotate ignore, save that image with OpenCV, then convert that to gray scale?

Comment: No, I mean open the image. Look at the EXIF information (see exiftool). Get the orientation flag. Use OpenCV to correct the orientation via rotation. Then do whatever else you need to do.